# Java - Two threads get into the same condition and pass

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am working on a **BTree** and I want to **synchronize** it but the problem is:

> I don't want to synchronize the whole method because it has a complex functionality.

My question is: how can I prevent first two or three threads from passing the first condition which `root==null`?

```
public void add(TrackingDevice device) {
    // Tree is Empty, then add a new elemet to root
    if (root == null ) {
        root = new BTreeNode(true);
        root.keys[0] = device;
        root.n++;
    } else {
        /*
        * The root is Full
        */
        if (root.n == 2 * t - 1) {
            splitRoot();
            root.insert(device);
            height++;
        } else {
            root.insert(device);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it's complex functionality argue in favor of **more** synchronization rather than less?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) with its compareAndSet method.

Then more than one thread may pass the condition root.get() == null and create the root node. But only the fastest thread will write the value via compareAndSet.

Answer (score 0):

I am just suggesting: implement a semaphore-like structure. Define a synchronized counter which your Threads will decrement each time they enter (be careful: this operation must be mutual exclusive) and prevent Threads from entering a section if counter == 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `AtomicReference<BTreeNode>` for the reference to the root node and use `compareAndSet(null, new BTreeNode(true))` to guard entrance to the `if` block. If the `add` method is called very frequently this approach ends up creating many short lived `BTreeNode` instances though. If this is a concern, you can check "manually" first whether the `AtomicReference` contains `null` and only if so call `compareAndSet`.

However, I would get rid of the `null` check entirely and initially set a root node with `n = 0`. This makes the code more uniform as then there is no need for checking whether the root exists.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I get rid of null check as you suggested and everything works fine at this stage, thanks again .